# List section in pdf bookmarks, but omit in LaTeX table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

Normally (under `pdflatex` with `hyperref`) a section added with `\section` will appear in both the LaTeX table of contents, and the pdf metadata; while a `\section*` will be omitted from both.

Is it possible to include a (sub)section in the metadata, but not list it in the TOC?

(The use-case in question is end-of-chapter exercises and notes in a book: we want to keep the TOC uncluttered, but having bookmarks for these in the pdf is very convenient.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The package `bookmark` provides a command `\bookmark[OPTIONS]{title}`.  You need to define a hypertarget and create a bookmark to it:

```
 \section*{Exercises and Notes}
 \hypertarget{exercises}{}
 \bookmark[level=section,dest=exercises]{Exercises and Notes}
```

`bookmark` should be loaded after `hyperref`.